# Element function fails to execute using external js

Tags: javascript, html, django

I just started learning JS and I keep failing to make a function successfully run via external javascript. I have no idea what is wrong. The thing is that it works when using inline javascript, but not external one. Here's the following code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

<title id='title'> Home </title>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="testas" onclick="myFunction()" />

<address>
    Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>
</address>

<script src="{% static 'javascript/js.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function ChangeTitle() {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = 'Homepage';
}
```

I want to change the title of "Home" to "Homepage" but it doesn't work on external JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your JS script you only created function, now you need to call it.

Just add ChangeTitle(); at the end of script.